# Export UIBezierPath on txt or plist file

Tags: plist, uibezierpath

I am referring [this](https://github.com/fmscode/DrawView) repository as reference.
I am new to UIBezierPath, In this repository developer has used one text file called "test-path.txt" which draws some text on the screen when loaded.

I want to create same kind of file with different letter in english.

Any knowledge on how to create that text file with UIBezierPath for different text.